# Sending value to a solidity contract method from web3 results in `Invalid Tuple Value` error

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm sending values to a solidity 0.5.1 method using web3js and keep getting an `invalid Tuple value` error.

Here's the relevant contract code:

```
struct mystruct {
    bytes32 id; 
    string str;
}

mapping (bytes32 => mystruct) structs;

function creatMyStruct(bytes32 id, string memory str) public {
    mystruct memory newStruct = mystruct(id, str);
    structs[id] = newStruct;
}
```

I'm calling this from `node.js`:

```
contract.methods.creatMyStruct(someId, someString).send({from: fromAccount, gas: gasEstimate})
    .then(receipt => {
       var txhash = receipt.transactionHash;
       resolve(txhash);
    },
    (error) => {
        reject(error);
    }).catch((err) => {
         reject(err);
    });
```

I tried sending a `string`, a `number`, and converting the string to `hex`. The same error: `invalid tuple value`. What am I missing?

Comment: maybe it helps https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38476/passing-bytes32-in-truffle-test

Comment: I went back to compiler version 0.4.24. Problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating new struct wrong. The problem is the contract. See the correct way

```
function creatMyStruct(bytes32 _id, string memory _str) public
{
    mystruct storage newStruct = mystruct({id: _id, str: _str});
    structs[id] = newStruct;
}
```

Comment: I tried, both for the `id` being `bytes32` and `string`. Still the same error.

Comment: Can you please replace this: `mystruct memory newStruct = mystruct(id, str);` to this: `mystruct storage newStruct = mystruct(id, str);` @Eddy

Comment: It doesn't compile, saying that `struct memory` is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct `storage pointer`. This is with Remix under 0.5.1.